# Keras - Error loading pre-trained network using keras in Google Colab

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I want to load the pre-trained networks to my Google Colab notebook using keras library.

I use the following code for this:

```
import keras
from keras.applications import VGG16, InceptionResNetV2, ResNet50
```

And I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-9c551e8fe84f> in <module>()
     15 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
     16 
---> 17 from keras.applications import VGG16, InceptionResNetV2, ResNet50

ImportError: cannot import name 'VGG16' from 'keras.applications' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

I used to do this and it worked well but now it gives the error. I do not know what the problem is!

It should be noted that when I do this on my device using Jupyter notebook, it works well and the network loads, but in Google Colab gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I answer it a bit late but I just have a similar error. Per [tensorflow's docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/VGG16), you need to fix `VGG16` to `vgg16` or you can go for:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2, ResNet50
```

It should work perfectly fine (as it is in my case)